# Are the tables in this ER diagram linked towards the employee table

Tags: mysql, database, erd

[image]

The tables should be linked mainly towards the employee table. Is this fine? I need to make connection to employee using foreign keys. Is it good practice to have this many foreign keys? Are they placed correctly? If not what should I do. Thanks in advance.

I am completely new to this and I don't have a clue as to what I am doing. pls hlp

Answer (score 0):

it will be better to make the relation many-to-many between **new_table** and **employee**

as you are doing: every employee has many new_table and every new_table has many employees SO (many-to-many)

you can draw the table between this relation like the **image** here
or
you can just draw the relation **>---<**

[image]